# How to sort an array of objects then map through it in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects of products, I'm trying to sort them on the ***price*** (Low to High) and (High to Low) and then map through the sorted array to display the product.

And I can sort it by the ***time*** to which in here referred to it by `created` means the time the product has been created And `updated` means the last time the product got modified.

- the JSX in the `map` because I'm using reactjs.

```js
const products = [
          {name: "keyboard",
           id: "1",
           created: 1614,
           updated: 1620,
           price: {
             raw: 1,
             formatted: "1.00",
             }
          },
          {name: "shoes",
           id: "2",
           created: 1655,
           updated: 1660,
           price: {
             raw: 2,
             formatted: "2.00",
             }
          },
          {name: "keyboard",
           id: "1",
           created: 1670,
           updated: 1670,
           price: {
             raw: 1,
             formatted: "1.00",
            }
          }
        ]
        
        
        const sortedProducts = //products after been sorted
        
        return(
          sortedProducts.map(product => 
            <div key={product.id}>
              <h1>{product.name}</h1>
              <h2>{product.price.formatted}</h2>
            </div>
        ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sort()` and compare the price property value

```js
const products = [{
    name: "keyboard",
    id: "1",
    created: 1614,
    updated: 1620,
    price: {
      raw: 1,
      formatted: "1.00",
    }
  },
  {
    name: "shoes",
    id: "2",
    created: 1655,
    updated: 1660,
    price: {
      raw: 2,
      formatted: "2.00",
    }
  },
  {
    name: "keyboard",
    id: "1",
    created: 1670,
    updated: 1670,
    price: {
      raw: 1,
      formatted: "1.00",
    }
  }
]

const sorted = products.sort((a, b) => a.price.formatted.localeCompare(b.price.formatted))

console.log(sorted);
```

Than you can map through the sorted array.

Answer (score 0):

To make it "runnable" I changed the last part back from JSX into JavaScript

```js
const products = [
      {name: "screen",
       id: "1",
       created: 1614,
       updated: 1620,
       price: {
         raw: 1.5,
         formatted: "1.50",
         }
      },
      {name: "shoes",
       id: "2",
       created: 1655,
       updated: 1660,
       price: {
         raw: 2,
         formatted: "2.00",
         }
      },
      {name: "keyboard",
       id: "1",
       created: 1670,
       updated: 1670,
       price: {
         raw: 1,
         formatted: "1.00",
        }
      }
    ]
    
    
    const sortedProducts = products.sort((a,b)=>a.created-b.created);
    document.getElementById('here').innerHTML=sortedProducts.map(product => 
     `<div key=${product.id}>
        <h1>${product.name}</h1>
        <h2>${product.price.formatted}</h2>
      </div>`
    ).join("\n")
```

```html
<div id="here"></div>
```

Instead of `created` you can fill in `updated` or `price.raw` for the other sort criteria.